# Have Premake generate a vcxproj file that refers to an existing .props file

Tags: visual-studio, premake, vcxproj

I am using a third party SDK that supplies a **.props** file that is used in the visual studio projects.

I generate my **.vcxproj** file with [Premake](https://github.com/premake/premake-core), as opposed to using the SDK's project wizard.

How can I tell Premake to generate the vcxproj file in such a way that it adds references to the third party **.props** file?

Currently, Premake adds to my vcxproj file:

```
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

Yet, I want it to be like this instead:

```
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="ACME_SDK.props" Condition="exists('ACME_SDK.props')" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

So one additional Import tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way afaik

you could look into overriding the propertySheets function

```
p.override(premake.vstudio.vc2010, 'propertySheets',  customPropertySheets)
```

where customPropertySheets is your function where you need to call the base function and add whatever else you need.